# Can't get 'autorange' for the y-axis to work in Plotly for Python

Tags: python, plotly

I created 4 subplots that are stacked vertically with their x-axes synchronized. My problem is that when I zoom in on one chart then the other chart's x-axis range is adjusted as desired, however, the y-axis is not adjusted. I want the y-axis range to rescale automatically so that the max value in the visible range is at the upper bound of the y-axis and accordingly for the min value on the lower bound. I tried to use the 'autorange' function but it does not seem to have any effect:

```
fig = make_subplots(rows=4, cols=1)
fig.append_trace(go.Line(x=df["Datetime"], y=df["Pnl"], name="Pnl"), row=1, col=1)
fig.append_trace(go.Line(x=df["Datetime"], y=df["USDCAD"], name="USDCAD"), row=2, col=1)
fig.append_trace(go.Line(x=df["Datetime"], y=df["USD"], name="USD"), row=3, col=1)
fig.append_trace(go.Line(x=df["Datetime"], y=df["USD_SMA30"], name="USD SMA"), row=3, col=1)
fig.append_trace(go.Line(x=df["Datetime"], y=df["CAD"], name="CAD"), row=4, col=1)
fig.append_trace(go.Line(x=df["Datetime"], y=df["CAD_SMA30"], name="CAD SMA"), row=4, col=1)

fig.update_layout(width=1000, height=2000)
fig.update_xaxes(matches='x')
fig.update_yaxes(autorange=True)
fig.show()
```

Comment: From reading the description of [this reference](https://plotly.com/python/reference/layout/xaxis/), wouldn't the y-axis also be accomplished by using congruence? In addition, an automatic range can be set. `fig.update_xaxes(matches='x');fig.update_xaxes(autorange=True);fig.update_yaxes(matches='y');fig.update_yaxes(autorange=True)`

Comment: This does not accomplish auto-ranging on the y-axis. It just sets the y-axis range of the synchronized y-axis to the y-axis range of the chart that is being interacted with. Auto-range on the y-axis should adjust the range of the y-axis of each chart to its own min and max y values not the values of a series/trace on a different chart.